# Sanity Check: SSL+ POST vs. un-encrypted GET

Tags: security, post, ssl

A classic dumb thing to do is pass something security related info via a GET on the query string ala:

```
http://foo?SecretFilterUsedForSecurity=username
```

...any yahoo can just use Fiddler or somesuch to see what's going on....

How safe is it to pass this info to an app server(running SSL) via a POST, however? This link from the Fiddler website seems to indicate one can decrypt HTTPS traffic:

http://fiddler2.com/documentation/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/DecryptHTTPS

So is this equally dumb if the goal is to make sure the client can't capture / read information you'd prefer them not to? It seems like it is.

Thanks.

Comment: If your goal is *obfuscated* communication not *secure* communication, then SSL won't help you.

Comment: If you want DRM you have to throw as much obfuscation as possible at the problem, and then pray that nobody competent bothers attacking it. It's impossible to get this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on who you're trying to protect your data from, and how much control you have over the client software. Fundamentally, in any client-server application the client must know what it is sending to the server.

If implemented properly, SSL will prevent any intermediary sniffing or altering the traffic without modifying the client. However, this relies on the connection being encrypted with a *valid* certificate for the server domain, and on the client refusing to act if this is not the case. Given that condition, the connection can only be decrypted by someone holding the private key for that SSL certificate.
If your "client" is just a web browser, this means that third parties (e.g. at a public wi-fi location) can't intercept the data without alerting the person using the site that something is suspicious. However, it doesn't stop a user deliberately by-passing that prompt in their browser in order to sniff the traffic themselves.

If your client is a custom, binary, application, things are a little safer against "nosy" users: in order to inspect the traffic, they would have to modify the client to by-pass your certificate checks (e.g. by changing the target URL, or tricking the app to trust a forged certificate).

In short, nothing can completely stop a determined user sniffing *their own* traffic (although you can make it harder) but properly implemented SSL will stop third-parties *intercepting* traffic.

Comment: This is mostly correct except for the part about 'only decrypted by someone holding the private key for that certificate'. The private key plays no part in the communication apart from establishing the identity of the server.

Comment: @EJP With plain RSA suites the server's private key is used to decrypt a shared session secret from which the session keys will be derived. So it's used not only for authenticating the server, but also for confidentiality. This makes weakens the key-exchange significantly compared to proper suites such as ECDHE_RSA where the server's private key is not involved in the key exchange itself and only identifies the server.

Comment: @EJP OK, I didn't realise that. So better to say "only intercepted by someone with a signed certificate for that domain (for use with a fake end point)"?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's "equally dumb". SSL only protects data from being read by a third party; it does not prevent the client (or the server) from reading it. If you do not trust the client to read some data, they should not be given access to that data, even just to make a POST.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, any user can easily examine the data in a POST request, even over HTTPS/SSL, using software like [Burp Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/), [Webscarab](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebScarab_Project), or [Paros Proxy](http://www.parosproxy.org/).  These proxies will complete the SSL transaction with the server, and then pass on the data to the client.  All data passing through the proxy is stored and is visible to the client.

Perhaps you are trying to store sensitive/secret data on the client-side to lighten the load on your server? the way to do this so that the user cannot look at it (or change it) even with a proxy, is to encrypt it with a strong symmetrical secret key known only to the server.   If you want to be sure that the encrypted data is not tampered with, throw on an [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code).  Make sure you use a sufficiently random key and a strong encryption algorithm and key length such as AES 256.

If you do this you can offload the storage of this data to the client but still have assurance that it has not changed since the server last saw it, and the client was not able to look at it.

Comment: A third party can only do that if one of the endpoints cooperates, is buggy, or CA gives them a fake key. The problem is that the OP isn't worried about third parties, he's assuming that the first party, the user wants to read their own communication.

Comment: @CodesInChaos whoops, I meant to say "a user" but said third-party instead :-O  My mind was thinking about something else.  I'll update the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The other, more important reason not to add confidential information into URL with GET requests is that the web server and any proxies on the way will log it. POST parameters don't get logged by default.

You don't want your passwords to show up in server logs - logs are usually protected much, much less than, for example, the password database itself.